# 'Trying to store an HTML table as a PHP variable, but built with a foreach loop. Possible?

Tags: php, html, loops

Hi I think this is just a syntax problem, but I might be doing something PHP isn't designed to do.

I'm trying to draw an HTML table, using an array to populate the table. The headers for example.

Where $headers is an array of headers I have attempted:

```
$html_table = '
                <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                    <tr>
                        foreach($headers as $header)
                        {
                        echo "<th> $header </th>";                          
                        }
                    </tr>
';
```

The idea being to generate:

```
 <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
        ...
        <th>Heading 99</th>
    </tr>
```

Simply by later asking for 
    $html_table

Suffice is to say at the moment I get a single headed column with "$header" in it, becuase the loop is not running inside the variable equation.

The reason I'm storing the HTML as a variable like this is because I want to concatenate (usage?) it with other generated html, i.e.

```
$html_table .= '</table>';
```

later on (of course the actual bit in the middle is more complicated, to do with retreiving data from databases to populate the table.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take the foreach out of the quotes

```
$html_table = '
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                <tr>';
foreach($headers as $header){
    $html_table .= "<th> $header </th>";                          
}
$html_table .='
                </tr>
';
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much, yes this works - I'll accept your answer when it lets me in 8 mins ;) you are fast!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> $html_table = '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"><tr>'; 
>
> foreach($headers as $header) 
>   { 
>     $html_table .= "<th>". $header."</th>";                           
>   }
>  $html_table .= '</tr>';
> ```

Comment: looks like horen beat me to it, plus 1 for him ;)

Comment: I upvoted you anyway @nathanhayfield as I think he edited your code in after his initial minimilistic reply. Thanks!
Also thanks for explaining the theory wiseguy

Comment: lol i'm too used to using smarty templates. they are more forgiving. @Wiseguy

Comment: FYI, normally you can't change votes, but if a question/answer is edited after you vote, your vote will be unlocked and allow you to change it. This is handy in a situation such as this, where I downvoted because it was wrong, but then you fixed it, so it no longer warranted my downvote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$html_table = '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"><tr>';

foreach($headers as $header)
{
    $html_table .=  '<th>'. $header .'</th>';                          
}
$html_table .= '</tr></table>';

echo $html_table;
```

This is pretty rancid though. You should consider not echoing out html in php...

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($headers AS $header): ?>
        <th><?php echo $header; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: eh, I have to work in smarty which makes escaping out to php like that clunky to do. I'd rather do it the latter way but for now I'm stuck with this. Thanks for your time